# How do I ensure that post_type and Taxonomy use the same slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, customization, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I had to create a Custom Post Type and taxonomy to add a question and answer section to my site. But I want both of them to use the same persistent link. The codes are like this, so one of the two doesn't work, how can I stop them from blocking each other?

The use I want it to be;
Custom Post Tyle: websitename.com/question-answer/question-title
Taxonomi: websitename.com/question-answer/category-name

```
function post_type_question_answer() {
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'question_answer_taxonomi'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'question-answer'
        ),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'question_answer', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_question_answer' );

register_taxonomy('question_answer_taxonomi', ['question_answer'], [
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'question-answer'
    )
]);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('question_answer_taxonomi', 'question_answer');
```

Comment: The issue here is that you are giving two distinct commands to the same "word", and when in the link there is call the "question-answer", wordpress will be a little confuse in what to do. The simplest way is to one "question-answerA" and other "question-answerB". Only using a different approach its possible to achieve the same and use only "question-answer" for both, like using php session or to send the variables in the url like so websitename.com/question-answer/category-name?vari=anwser&vari2=answer2

Comment: The use the same slug, even being possible wp hasnt design to use the same  slug for different purposes  in the url. so maybe its not the best practice.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this but I have seen a lot of Wordpress sites that do this. I want to get him to allow it in some way and use the same permalink.